# Is it good for list item to hold the reference of a context in android

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

Recently I run into an argument about this, is it good practice for list item to hold the reference of a context.
Let's say this is a recyclerView, an adapter, and many items to hold the data. And my item class looks like:

```
class Item(private val data: SomeData, private val context: Context) {
    
    val xxFile: File get() {
        // do something with context and return a File
    }
}
```

Then I can use this item can some place else, and easily get the result file like

```
fun onClick(item: Item) {
    val file = item.xxFile
    // do some thing with the file
}
```

My point is that keep the context inside the item is easy to use, I can write getXX() function as 'val', and I can just call item.xxFile to get result I want. But I wonder it is good to do so, or it will make some memory leak or something.

So far I did not meet the 'memory leak problem', and in my activity's onCreate, I did not use the savedInstanceState but initialize everything like a new instance. I just feel it is not good to code like this.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: It can lead to memory leaks if you are not careful and do not keep track where do you hold a reference to a context. It is better to avoid any context references. Basically, you should almost never store a reference to the context because in every place where you need one - you should already have one. For example, in every `ViewHolder` you can get the context by calling `itemView.getContext()`; in every adapter in `onCreateViewHolder` you have `ViewGroup` as an argument and it as well has `getContext()` method, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I will use this item somewhere else not just in adapter. Like in onItemClicked, I can pass it to the presenter class, then use it when user click save button. In fact, I only use this item in origin activity where it got constructed, I think so far is safe.

Comment: You can pass in the context as method argument when user clicks save button, use the context inside of that save method and not hold the reference.

Comment: Yes, I can pass context as parameter, just wonder how bad it could be if I keep context in recycler item. Also, thanks for your comments.

Comment: "how bad it could" - If we consider the worst-case scenario it could be pretty bad. Each individual case has to examined to identify how bad is it. To avoid even thinking about it - do not store references and it will be better immediately.

Comment: It is safe to reference the Application, because the Application instance cannot be leaked. So you could store a reference to Application, and get its `context` property when you need it.

Comment: Thanks, that's an other solution.